# Is it possible to get the pixel color in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, colors, foreground, getpixel

This is my first time that 
 I want to make a simple app that will detect color of the current pixel by specifying X and Y coordinates of the main screen or other app like game.
 So if it is possible please give me function name or give me an example!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Canvas for that, together with the SurfaceView view. Then you will be able to select a pixel from the canvas and get its color values.

Comment: thanks, but i need a role to get pixel color from another UI. I set my APP with service to run background. I need to get pixel color from (x , y) like (80,130). form background or another APP like game or .... . I need too get color and comparison with other color ( like : FF9988AA) . if base color match with other APP color then start other service. thanks dude